# If Statements Gone Wrong

Tags: javascript

Perhaps I am forgetting about a rule of some sort.
It should be obvious to tell what I want to do. It seems no matter what is entered and stored for the 'sph' variable, the only alert I get is the first one. If anything I would expect the 'else' statement to work. I've tried different ways like using the '==' and '===' operators. I've also changed it to a 'switch' statement, used 'if's instead of 'else if's, and also tried nesting. I'm not seeing any syntax mistakes so my next guess is that I can't access arrays in the way that I am trying to.

Note: the second prompt input is intended to be a negative number; in case you are wondering why I have 'cyl <= 0'.

```
var sph = prompt("What is the sphere power?");
var cyl = prompt("What is the cylinder power?");

var sixSevenFive = [6.5, 6.25, 6];
var six = [5.75, 5.5, 5.25];
var five = [5, 4.75, 4.5, 4.25];
var fourFive = [4.0, 3.75, 3.5];
var four = [3.25, 3.00, 2.75, 2.5, 2.25, 2, 1.75, 1.5, 1.25, 1, .75, .5, .25];


if ((sph = four) && (cyl <= 0)) {
alert("Use a 4.00 Base lens.");
}

else if ((sph = fourFive) && (cyl <= 0)){
alert("Use a 4.50 Base lens.");
}

else if ((sph = five) && (cyl <= 0)){
alert("Use a 5.25 Base lens.");
}

else if ((sph = six) && (cyl <= 0)){
alert("Use a 6.00 Base lens.");
}

else if ((sph = sixSevenFive) && (cyl <= 0)){
alert("Use a 6.75 Base lens.");
}

else {
alert("You entered an invalid prescription.");
}
```

Comment: when comparing, use `===` and not `=` witch assigns a variable

Comment: "I've tried different ways like using the '==' and '===' operators. " I disagree...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can't use equality operators (`==` and `===`, not `=`!) to check for a value in an array. Use something like this instead:

```
if(four.indexOf(sph) > -1 && cyl <= 0) { // etc
```

Also, use `parseFloat` on your inputs to make sure you compare numbers to numbers (not strings):

```
var sph = parseFloat(prompt("What is the sphere power?"));
var cyl = parseFloat(prompt("What is the cylinder power?"));
```

**Demo**: http://jsfiddle.net/Wmesx/

Comment: This indexOf is new to me but sounds like it should work.  
Also, do you mean:  
`if((four.indexOf(sph) > -1) && (cyl <= 0))`  
Regardless, I can't implement it effectively, that is, I can't make it give me a simple alert inside the if statement. I type "2" and "-1", respectively(and without quotes of course) in the prompts but nothing happens.

Comment: Keep in mind [`indexOf`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/indexOf) is not supported on IE<=8, so you may need a polyfill (see MDN for one). The inner parentheses are optional, you can keep them if you think they improve readability. And I believe you need to use parseFloat on your inputs, see my update.

Comment: I can't imagine ever using Internet Explorer haha. So it turns out, somehow I did not learn that data stored in a variable from a prompt command is translated into string data. But you've been a big help in helping me with this. Thank you.

Answer (score 3):

You've repeatedly used the `=` operator when you want the `==` operator. The first assigns a value. The second is a test. `===` also tests whether the data types are the same, and is often preferable.

And bfavaretto's point.

Comment: Did no one notice OP is comparing a string to an array

Answer (score 1):

You're using an assignment operator when you should be using an == or an === operator.

See http://www.w3schools.com/js/js_comparisons.asp

Comment: Not sure that wsschools is a great reference site. See [w3fools](http://www.w3fools.com/)

Comment: That's a list of operators. What part of that table is in error?

Comment: If you want a great reference, read Javascript: The Good Parts

Answer (score 0):

Equality is tested using `==` operator.